# How to use jQuery AJAX in ember v3.2.5?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, ember.js

I tried writing code that gives the alert message inside the function but the success or error block seems doesn’t work.

How can I call the function properly? I'm using the latest Ember version (3.2.5).
Here is my AJAX code in the app/controller

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import $ from 'jquery';
export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    validateUser: function() {
      let res = this;
      var userName = this.get('username');
      var userPassword = this.get('password');

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "InsertServlet",
        data: {
          userId: userName,
          password: userPassword
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == 1) {
            alert('valid user');
          } else {
            alert("Invalid User");
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to invoke the `validateUser` action in the template for this controller. If the controller is `app/controllers/login.js` then the template would be `app/templates/login.hbs`. Add `<button {{on "click" (action "validateUser)}}>Login</button>` there are when you click that button the action would fire.

However, if you're working with the current `3.25` version of ember you may want to rewrite this using the more idiomatic [octane](https://emberjs.com/editions/octane/) and JS approach.  Which would look like:

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class LoginController extends Controller {
  @action
  async validateUser(){
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {userId: this.username, password: this.password },
    });
    console.log(response);
  }
}
```

And then the button would look like:

```
<button {{on "click" this.validateUser}}>Login</button>
```